# Swagger Reference Object ($ref) in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, swagger

Swagger definition can contain JSON References ($ref), for example:

```
{"paths": {
            "/malts": {
                "get": {
                    "responses": {
                        "200": {
                            "schema": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/Malt"
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
       }
    }
```

Storing this JSON Object in MongoDB seems to work, but when updating it later I get the following error:

> MongoError: The DBRef $ref field must be following by a $id field

Does this really mean that JSON References cannot be stored in a MongoDB because Mongo uses $ref also for [their internal database reference](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is in your usage of the mongodb driver.  What client library, and which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the lastest version of mongo-express (https://github.com/andzdroid/mongo-express)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem while trying to store json schema objects in Mongo (with $ref keys).

I was able to work around the problem by using this very simple mongo object escaping library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-json-escape

Simple Example:

```
var mje = require('mongo-json-escape');
var safeToStoreObject = mje.escape({"hello$world":"hello"});
var readyToUseObject = mje.unescape({"hello\uFF04world":"hello"});
```

Comment: Be very careful that you run the unescape process wherever you are pulling relevent items out of mongo.  The escaped character looks very close to the dollar sign (they are using "U+FF04 : FULLWIDTH DOLLAR SIGN" as the escape character, which of course, looks like a dollar sign)

Comment: In the MongoDB docs it states that fields  can not start with dollar sign "$ "and can not contain a period ".": https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/